# What estimation method establishes sample mean and sample variance as estimators of mean and variance?

Tags: variance, estimation, maximum-likelihood, mean

Sample mean and sample variance can be derived as MLE estimators for the mean and variance of a normal distribution.

For a distribution in general, what kind of estimation method   leads to sample mean and sample variance as estimators of its mean and variance?

Thanks.

Comment: U-statistics would be an approach that automatically ensures unbiasedness and minimum variance.

Comment: I do not think sample variance is the MLE estimator of variance under normality; the two estimators differ by a factor of $(n-1)/n$ (unless you define sample variance as the MLE estimator, i.e. the biased one).

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes, I mean the latter

Comment: @Tim, thank you for the clarification. I think this is uncommon to define sample variance in such a way, but at least it is clear what you meant.

Answer (score 4):

I’m not sure what you are actually asking, but by the plug-in principle, the sample mean and sample variance are nonparametric estimators of the population mean and population variance for any distribution (provided they exist), and you can obtain their sampling distributions via bootstrapping.

Answer (score 1):

I just realize the method is called method of moments (MOM).

Comment: I think the MOM estimator of variance differs by a factor of $(n-1)/n$ from the MLE estimator of variance under normality.